# Python - Find a list within a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, where each list may be of arbitrary length for example:

```
list_of_lists = [[2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 6]]
```

I need a way to search that list of lists for a specific list. For example, a `contains()` function which would return `True` below:

```
list_of_lists.contains([2, 2, 6])
```

I have seen answers where the "inner lists" can be converted into tuples, but that doesn't help me here. Is there a library out there that has this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple answers suggesting to use `in` or `==` to see if the list contains the element (another list). 
However, if you do not care about the order of the elements in the lists you are comparing, here is a solution to that.

```
import collections

# 'list_' is the list we are searching for in a bigger list 'list_of_lists'
for element in list_of_lists:
    if collections.Counter(element) == collections.Counter(list_) :
        return True
```

The above solution requires the elements to be hashable.

If you find `collections` too complicated to understand, you can simply use `set(list_) == set(element)`.

The above methods require elements to be hashable.
If the elements are not hashable but sortable, you can use `sorted(list_)==sorted(element)`.

Comment: So lists in python are not hashable, but in the example the items in the "inner lists" are hashable. Does that mean that the above code would work or not? And what is the meaning of the second line, collections.Counter(x) == collections.Counter(y)? That doesn't seem to be used in the rest of the snippet

Comment: The code will work because, here we are not trying to hash the list, but the elements in the smaller lists inside `list_of_lists` (which are numbers in your example). I have added two alternatives in case you want to have some other elements (not `int`) inside the lists which are not hashable.

Comment: @Shanna Mae, I just updated my answer, the duplicated line was a typo. Also, by `The above solution requires the elements to be hashable.` I meant the elements of the list we pass to `collections.Counter()` method. And in our case here, that list is a list of integers, so it will work with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `in`:

```
list_of_lists = [[2,2,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,2,6]]

if [2,2,6] in list_of_lists:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
found
```

Similarly, let's say the last list in the nested list was: `[2, 2, 6, 8]`

```
list_of_lists = [[2,2,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,2,6,8]]

if [2,2,6] in list_of_lists:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
not found
```

**EDIT**:

While I was at it, if you wanted to have a boolean value for the existance of the list:

```
def chkList(lst):
    return True if lst in list_of_lists else False

list_of_lists = [[2,2,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,2,6]]
print(chkList([2,2,6]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
True
```

Comment: a possibly more interesting example would be finding a subset of a list within a list of lists. What if the final list in `list_of_lists` was actually `[2, 2, 6, 8]` and OP still wanted to find it. I'm not saying that's what they're looking for (_at all_), just that that's a non-trivial case :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Ah, not really, if the last list in the nested list is lets say `[2, 2, 6, 8]` the condition would return false.

Comment: right. The question I was posing was to produce code that would return a `True` result if any of the lists _contained_ the argument, not just _was_ the argument. It's a step and a half above what OP is looking for, but it's at least interesting :)

Comment: @AdamSmith There, I made something. :3

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
print([2,2,6] in list_of_lists)
```

<strike>Or use `__contains__`:</strike>

```
print(list_of_lists.__contains__([2,2,6]))
```

(DON'T USE `__contains__`, HIGHLY UN-RECOMENDED)

Answer (score 0):

What if you dosomething like

```
if any(list == [2, 2, 6] for list in list_of_lists):
    #execute whatever code you want for this case
```

Comment: This is just `in` (except potentially slightly worse, since I think list `__contains__` gets inlined to C functions, while `any(lst == [2, 2, 6] for ...)` can't.)

Comment: But it's not wrong and therefore doesn't deserve a downvote IMHO. It's just another option.

Comment: Lots of code produces the same results as faster, more readable, more maintainable code. You still call it wrong :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I had assumed the eventual goal would be to take some action in the event the list is contained, but now I see the question asks for a Boolean method that returns whether it is contained.  Thanks for the info regarding __contains__.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you needed a more generic solution checking if your target list is actually an *ordered* sublist of one of inner lists. The trick would be converting the list into a string representation that allows efficient substring checking.

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[2,2,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,2,6,8]]
>>> serialize = lambda x: ','.join(map(str,x))
>>> any(serialize([2,2,6]) in serialize(item) for item in list_of_lists)
True
>>> any(serialize([2,2,7]) in serialize(item) for item in list_of_lists)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code from ipython

```
In [18]: list
Out[18]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 4]]

In [19]: def contains(sublist):
             if sublist in list:
                  return True
             else:
                  return False
   ....:             

In [20]: contains([1,2,3])
True

In [21]: contains(2)
False

In [22]:
```